# Why is my 4TB hard drive only letting me use 200GB?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

It shows up as 3.67 TB or something similar when I get to the partition setup. It has no problem partitioning and booting up, but it's only letting me use 200GB-ish. This is a fresh install, so I don't have a 3tb trash bin.

My virtual disk/RAID controller shows it as 3.xx TB as well.

My `df -h -x{tmp,devtmp,squash}fs` results are here.

[image: Results from df -h]

UPDATE:
I have an lvm partition on that drive of 200gb as my home directory.

Comment: Please edit your question with clearer details about the status and setup of all of the partitions on this drive.  It sounds like you are telling us that your root partition is only 200GB, but the details you provided are ambiguous/unclear.  Please **do not** submit pictures or screenshots of your terminal.  Instead copy/paste commands with the corresponding terminal output and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to preserve line breaks and monospace formatting.

Comment: *I have an lvm partition on that drive of 200gb as my home directory* This is your answer.